# Streams from outlet using QGIS

Tags: qgis, hydrology-toolset

I have an outlet (point inside a polygon, see the image below) and using global mapper I have computed the basin leading to this outlet.

I want also to get the main water channel of this basin in order to calculate the time of concentration, but I could not figure out how to do that. Below is an image of the data:

[image]

I want to use QGIS.

Comment: In the toolbox you will find some tools for hydrology : GRASS r.watershed , SAGA Terrain Analsysis-Hydrology

Comment: Do you only have contour data, or do you have a DEM? If you only have contour data, you will need to interpolate a DEM from it.

Comment: I have DEM and I have generated contours from DEM